# How to collapse jUnit output to summary, using ANT?

Tags: ant, junit

**My test target looks as follows:**

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
    <junit haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="bin" />
            <pathelement location="lib/xstream-1.4.2.jar" />
            <pathelement location="lib/jettison-1.2.jar" />
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />

        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${test-src}">
                <include name="**/*Test*" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

**And output looks as follows:**

```
test:
    [junit] Testsuite: app.commons.error.test.ShellErrorMessageTest
    [junit] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testCreateNormal took 0.003 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetSectionSeparatorLine took 0.001 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetSectionSeparatorLineMultipleSymbols took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetSectionSeparatorLineEmptySymbol took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetSectionSeparatorLineEmptySymbolSpace took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetSectionSeparatorLineNull took 0 sec
```

**How can i collapse this output to a 1 line summary?**

Is there a way to receive 1 line output along the line of "Ran 500 tests. 0 Failures. 0 Errors"

Answer (score 1):

You can set an unverbose junit-output by adding

```
 <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
```

within `<junit>`.

To further reduce it, the following options come to my mind:

- use a standard unix/cygwin tool to filter the output,
- add a `<junitreport>`-task within `<junit>`, or
- check the [free exemplary chapter "Testing with JUnit" from "Java Development with Ant](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/ant/ant_chap04.pdf), they probably have some advice for you in there.